# on clicking the edit button how to extract only those textboxes which are filled in php

Tags: php

on clicking the edit button how to extract only those text boxes which are filled in php.

I have altogether 6 fields:id,type,caption,path,dynamictext,time.
On clicking edit button if type=0 then it need to extract id,caption,path and time.
On clicking edit button if type=1 then it need to extract id,caption,dynamictext and time.

Since when clicking on edit button if type 0 the dynamictext field is empty and likewise the path is empty if i click on edit button.

How can i extract only the filled textbox?????Please help me.

Comment: Maybe add some code, so we can see the problem :)

Comment: UPDATE tbl_content SET id ='$id_save',
         caption='$caption_save',
         path='$path_save',
         dynamictext='$dynamictext_save',
         time='$time_save'
         where id=".$_GET['id']."